# Copy/Delete Sharpeoint Library items to another Sharpeoint Library between date using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, csom

I hope you can help with this topic, please explain the scenario.

I have a site in Sharepoint online.

-I have an origin (Sharepoint library) that contains photos.

My doubt is how to copy the items (origin) to a new destination(Sharepoint library), when you finish copying delete the items copied from the origin, or just move the items ?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps if you are using SharePoint online

1. Select the item
2. Click on "Move to" from the menu on top
3. Select the destination from the right hand pop-up
4. Select the destination library
5. Finally click on "Move"

[image]

Comment: Dear, thank you for your answer, the drawback is that the items exceed 5000 and I would like to move them dynamically

Comment: I see. In that case you'll need to write a script to move all the items' attachment one by one to the destination library. I'm sure you can find some JavaScript/REST scripts online. If you don't find, let me know, I will write something